# How to pass inside a function an argument which is an access properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a function in javascript ES6 which takes 3 arguments:

1. isSelected - a true/false OBJ which indicated if something selected or not
2. actual - an OBJ which indicates the actual selected param
3. value - this is the accessing properties to add to isSelected or to actual.

What I tried to do:

```
export const checkSelected = (isSelected, actual, value) => {
  return isSelected ? isSelected.`${value}` : actual.value;
};
```

but I don't know how to pass value after the dot.

This function says if it is selected response with `isSelected.value` which is the accessing properties I need to display from that OBJ.
If it does not show the other one.

I would like to know how I could pass the `.value` as a parameter to the function.

As no clear this is an example of what I need to do:

What I want to pass is that I have 3 arguments the value argument is the value you add to an OBJ to access specific properties like:

```
selectedObj: {  
     prop1
     prop2
} 

actualOBJ {
     prop1
     prop2
}
```

Then my function will do

```
func(selectedObj, actualOBJ, prop1) {
  if selectedOBJ {
   selectedOBJ.prop1
} else {

 actualOBJ.prop1
}

}
```

Comment: Wild guess: You want to do `return isSelected ? isSelected[value] : actual.value;`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you're asking how to access a property names by a string you'd use bracket notation.

Comment: What I want to pass is that I have 3 arguments the value argument is the value you add to an OBJ to access specific properties like:

selectedObj: {.   
     prop1
     prop2
} 

actualOBJ {
     prop1
     prop2
}

So I have the func(selectedObj, actualOBJ, prop1) 

I want to if selectedOBJ do slectedOBJ.prop1 else actualOBJ.prop1

I want a function which will d that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to check if isSelected exists and if does, you want to take out the "property value" of isSelected, else the value is the to be fetched from "actual" object.

Here is how you can do it:

```js
const checkSelected = (isSelected, actual, value) => {
  return(typeof isSelected !== 'undefined' ? isSelected[value] : actual[value]);
};

const actual = {
  "test": 123
}

const isSelected = {
  "test": 145
}

console.log(checkSelected(isSelected, actual, "test"))
```